# VBA Code to highlight a certain range (addition to email code)

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have the code below which sends an email out depending on the data inputted onto the spreadsheet.

As you can see the range in which the email is sent is to do with row number entered in B1(+1) and up to and including the row number entered in B2. I want to add to this code so it also colours the row. We have 6 different emails which could be sent depending on the button hit and we want the row to be a different colour per email sent.

```
Sub SendEmail(what_address As String, subject_line As String, mail_body As String)

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

olMail.To = what_address
olMail.Subject = subject_line
olMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
olMail.HTMLBody = mail_body
olMail.Send

End Sub
```

.

```
Sub Del24Hrs()

row_number = Sheet1.Range("B1")

Do
DoEvents
row_number = (row_number + 1)
Dim mail_body_message As String
Dim To_Name As String
Dim Order_No As String
Dim RN_No As String

mail_body_message = Sheet2.Range("A1")
subject_line = "Envirovent Order Confirmation"
To_Name = Sheet1.Range("D" & row_number)
Order_No = Sheet1.Range("G" & row_number)
RN_No = Sheet1.Range("A" & row_number)
mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "Replace_To_Name", To_Name)
mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "Replace_Order_No", Order_No)
mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "Replace_RN_No", RN_No)

Call SendEmail(Sheet1.Range("F" & row_number), "Envirovent Order Confirmation", mail_body_message)
Loop Until row_number = Sheet1.Range("B2")

End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: So, after each loop, you want to color the cell that was used? What color? Do you want to color the row, or just the A, D, G columns of `row_number`?

Comment: Hi , Yes I do. Yellow. The whole row please

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to color red if the user pushes button 1. The color for that is RGB(255,0,0). Insert a shape as the button, right click and select 'assign macro' and then assign the sub Button1Click.

This should paint the ranges that are used to send emails. You can change RGB numbers to come up with different colors easily. Play with font color in an Excel sheet (go to more colors) to choose your numbers and then create similar subs for other 5 buttons:

**'Assign this code to button 1:**

```
Sub Button1Click()
    Call Del24Hrs(RGB(255, 0, 0))
End Sub
```

**Code to send emails and color the ranges used:**

```
Sub Del24Hrs(lColor As Long)
    Dim mail_body_message As String
    Dim To_Name As String
    Dim Order_No As String
    Dim RN_No As String
    Dim rng As Range

    row_number = Sheet1.Range("B1")

    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1")

    Do
        DoEvents
        row_number = (row_number + 1)

        mail_body_message = Sheet2.Range("A1")
        subject_line = "Envirovent Order Confirmation"
        To_Name = Sheet1.Range("D" & row_number)
        Order_No = Sheet1.Range("G" & row_number)
        RN_No = Sheet1.Range("A" & row_number)

        Set rng = AddRange(rng, To_Name)
        Set rng = AddRange(rng, Order_No)
        Set rng = AddRange(rng, RN_No)

        mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "Replace_To_Name", To_Name)
        mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "Replace_Order_No", Order_No)
        mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "Replace_RN_No", RN_No)

        Call SendEmail(Sheet1.Range("F" & row_number), "Envirovent Order Confirmation", mail_body_message)
    Loop Until row_number = Sheet1.Range("B2")

    'Color the range at once
    rng.Interior.Color = lColor

End Sub
```

**Code to union ranges that are used during sending emails:**

```
Function AddRange(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range) As Range
    Set AddRange = Application.Union(rng1, rng2)
End Function
```

Comment: Hi, I seem to get an error at the area highlighted saying 'ByRef Argument Type Mismatch', it highlight the To_Name part

        Set rng = AddRange(rng, To_Name)

Comment: @R.Heppy could you send a snapshot of the data? and the error? This is a simple debugging and you should be able to find out why. I guess there is sth wrong with on of the cell values and it is where it stops. Or you can send me the whole excel file so that I can have a look quickly. There is no need to have the email addresses, you can use dummy addresses